# How do I get csv + json data in tabular form in R language

Tags: r

id,event,event_timestamp,properties
43e172a91,Cart is viewed,2016-08-19 02:07:56.88,"{""email_id"": ""chem@gmail.com"", ""timeStamp"": ""29-08-2016 07:43:10"", ""No Of Products"": 1, ""Cart Value"": ""1495""}"

Comment: (1) please *summarize* your question in the topic/subject, and ask the meat of the question in the question-body; (2) learn how to [format text and code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help); (3) have you tried anything? CSV is about as basic and first-hour-of-R-class as you can get, indicating you've done absolutely no research. Please, SO should not be your first stop for questions, a little research (whether on SO, Google, Bing, or [RSeek](https://rseek.org/)) will likely answer it much faster than you can get down-votes here.

Answer (score 1):

Try using fromJSON function from jsonlite package

```
install.packages("jsonlite")
library(jsonlite)
```

these are original examples from package documentation.

```
fromJSON('{"city" : "Z\\u00FCrich"}')

data3 <- fromJSON("https://api.github.com/users/hadley/repos", flatten = TRUE)
```

To read csv files, there is read.csv function in base R

```
mydf <- read.csv("C:/myfile.csv")
```

Comment: I believe the JSON is in the fourth column, so the complexity here is `jsonlite::fromJSON(mydf$properties[1])` (for the first) or `lapply(mydf['properties'], jsonlite::fromJSON)` for all.